# Incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to Comparable<Object>[]

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I am new to generics and casting issues. I try to sort any type array that is comparable. The error is as the title; and the code is as below: and error is same for integer. What is the problem and why?

```
class Sort{
  public static void selectionSort(Comparable<Object>[] input)
  {/* selection Sort Alg*/}
  public static void main((String[] args){
    int[] intArray = {2,3,5,1};
    Sort.selectionSort(intArray);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1. `int` is a POD, not an object. Boxing and unboxing from `int[]` to corresponding `Integer[]` is not automatically performed. You need to declare `intArray` as:

   ```
   Integer[] intArray = {2,3,5,1};
   ```
2. `Integer` implements `Comparable<Integer>`, not `Comparable<Object>`. The two specializations are different and incompatible types. The right way to declare `selectionSort` is by using generics, as you suggest in the title:

   ```
   public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void selectionSort(T[] input)
   ```

Comment: Yours work, but there appear an error in compareTo method:    private static <T> boolean less(Comparable<T> a, Comparable<T> b){
    return a.compareTo(b) < 0;
  } Showing the error is "Comparable<T> is incompatible to T". How to fix that?

Comment: It works! Can you explain what are the differences between your two answers?

Comment: @Peterxwl, static <T> boolean less<Comparable<T> left, T right), as you compare the generic parameter of Comparable implementation. But the best choice is to use a Comparator instead of Comparable

Comment: @Peterxwl in the first one, each element of the array was a `Comparable<T>`, in the second, each element is of type `T`, which is a subclass of `Comparable<T>`. Without looking at `insertionSort` implementation, it is hard to tell where it broke, but probably you tried to assign an element of `input` (static type `Comparable<T>`) to a variable with static type `T`, which is not possible without a downcast.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues in your code snippet

The fist one is with the argument of your method, lets look on this example

`void simple(Comparable<Object> input) {}`

This simple method expect a instance of `Comparable<Object>`.

To create a instance for that you could implement class like:

`class MyComparable implements Comparable<Object> {}`

What you must by aware is that genericType ( className ), assure your type safety. This mean that:

- `Comparable<String>` can compare only String objects
- `Comparable<Object>` can compare only Object objects

You can not really on class hierarchy in term of generic parameters.

The class `Integer` implements `Comparable<Integer>` so to be able to use that you can do this:

`void simple(Comparable<Integer> input) {}`

The you will be able pass everything that implements `Comparable<Integer>`.

With arrays is the same rule,

`void array(Comparable<Integer>[] input) {}`

but what you should keep in mind is that `int[]` is not the same as `Integer[]` JVM use different operations for those types.

An `int[]` stores primitive integer values. 
And `Integer[]` stores references to `Integer` class.

- `Comparable<Integer>[] array = {1,2,3,4};` is not allowed
- `Comparable<Integer>[] array = new Integer[] {1,2,3,4};` is valid statement

Answer (score 0):

int is a primitive, you should use Integer. You have an already sort method that sorts Integer:

```
class Sort{
  public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        intList.add(2);
        intList.add(3);
        intList.add(5);
        intList.add(1);
        Collections.sort(intList);
        System.out.println(intList.toString());
      }
}
```

Comment: try to use directly : Collections.sort(intArray);

Comment: If you think that this will help `Peterxwl` more, then edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generics only work with Object, not with primitive types. Fortunately, you can find some useful wrapper classes into the package java.lang, like the object Integer.
Your code will become:

```
Integer[] intArray = new Integer[]{2,3,5,1};
Sort.selectionSort(intArray);
```

I suggest to change the parameter into the selectionSort: you don't want a `Comparable<Object>`, but a generic `T<extends Comparable<? super T>>`; in other words you need a parameter which extends a class which can compare T and theirs superclasses

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works. Search google for more details.

```
    public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr1 ={"a","b","c"};
        Float[] arr2 ={1.1f, 1.2f, 1.3f};
        Integer[] arr3 = {1,2,3};
        Object[][] arr = {arr1,arr2,arr3};
        System.out.println(arr[1][1]);
    }
   }
```